# Is there a way of getting notified by Windows C API that cursor has changed?

Tags: windows, cursor

I would like to be notified that the windows cursor has changed, so that I can capture
the cursor as a bitmap. I have searched through the API documents, but there doesn't seem to be any way, other than polling the cursor state.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it. It requires us to use SetWinEventHook
to be notified of curser events:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151116-00/?p=92091